# How do I choose NSThread over NSTimer?

Tags: cocoa-touch, nstimer, nsthread

In other words, if I have a process that continuously runs, but users can change parameters on the GUI that effect the process operation characteristics, where is a better place to put the process, in a `NSThread` or `NSTimer`?

Comment: They are two separate constructs for two separate things, and not comparable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [`NSThread`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsthread_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [`NSTimer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) are two separate things for different needs, lets compare the two functions:

Using `NSThread`:

```
-(void) doSomethingEverySecond {
     __block int cumValue = 0; // cumulative value
     __block void(^execBlock)() = ^{        
        while (1)
        {
            @try 
            {
                // some code here that might either A: call continue to continue the loop, 
                // or B: throw an exception.
                cumValue++;
                NSLog(@"Cumulative Value is: %i", cumValue);

                if (cumValue == 5)
                    return;
            }
            @finally 
            {
                [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
            }
        }
    };

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(invoke) toTarget:[execBlock copy] withObject:nil];
}
```

Using `NSTimer`:

```
-(void) doSomethingEverySecond {
    __block NSTimer *timer = nil;
    __block int cumValue = 0;
    __block void (^execBlock)() = ^{
        cumValue++;
        NSLog(@"Cumulative Value is: %i", cumValue);

        if (cumValue == 5)
            [timer invalidate];
    };

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:[execBlock copy] selector:@selector(invoke) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Now, if we want to something only once, `NSThread` is the way to go, as shown in the following:

```
-(void) doSomethingOnce {    
    __block void (^execBlock)() = ^{
        NSLog(@"Doing something that could take a LONG time!");
    };

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(invoke) toTarget:[execBlock copy] withObject:nil];
}
```

Now, for the `NSTimer` variant:

```
-(void) doSomethingOnce {    
    __block void (^execBlock)() = ^{
        NSLog(@"Doing something that could take a LONG time!");
    };

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0 target:[execBlock copy] selector:@selector(invoke) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

The reason for this is that we have complete control over the thread while using a `NSThread`, but if using a `NSTimer`, than we are executing inside a `NSRunLoop` which may freeze the UI if any heavy lifting is done inside. THAT is the advantage of a `NSThread` over a `NSTimer`.

You are also guaranteed that a `NSThread` that is detached is executed immediately, with a `NSTimer`, which is based on NSRunLoop, cannot, as it may or may not be able to execute immediately.

There is a 3rd alternative (well technically a fourth too, `pthread`s, but I will ignore that for now), `GCD`, but I would suggest you RTFM on that, as it's too broad of a topic to cover in this post.

Answer (score 1):

NSThread and NSTimer are not mutually exclusive or replacements for one another. NSThread allows you to control a thread of execution and NSTimer is just that, a timer.

I assume you mean running an NSTimer on a background thread rather than on the main thread? That is generally a good idea so that the timer has less potential to be delayed by things occurring on your main thread (such as user interaction with the application).

You should read [Apple's Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html).